# RPi3 Raspbian SD card size

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I'm trying to expand my rootfs to the 64Gb size of my micro SD card on Raspbian Jessie, on a RPi3. The initial attempt by `raspi-config` to resize the filesystem seems to succeed and it prints the

> Resized filesystem rebooting in 5 seconds

message. However upon reboot the size is still 4.5Gb using the `df -h` command.. An external Linux PC which saw the volume as 4.5Gb before the initial resize now sees it as 62.5Gb, so supposedly the resize did succeed. No matter how many times I reboot on my RPi though I still see 4.5Gb. I did read that the max supported SD size is 32Gb, but it seems unlikely that this would cause the size to appear as 4.5Gb while the card works properly in general. Of course I could be wrong here, so any ideas on what's going wrong would be really appreciated.

Comment: Need more information.  Such as, are you installing from NOOBS?

Comment: No, downloading Raspbian image directly. I've actually just managed to solve the issue, I'll post the solution in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I followed to solve this problem:

1. Inserted the SD card into a separate Linux PC.
2. Unmounted the mmcblk0p2 partition (the one that showed up at 62.5Gb on said PC) via the app launcher (right click on the volume icon and click unmount).
3. Ran `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mmcblk0p2`. Answered y (yes) to its
   suggested fixes.
4. Ran `sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2` and waited for it to finish.

The root partition now shows up as 62.5Gb on the RPi3.

Comment: Coolness.  Great job!